# IdentityServer4 + ASP.Identity - Authenticate different user types from different databases

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

At first, the application had regular Users that were able to authenticate using ASP.Identity + IdentityServer4 (OpenId Connect).

Later Employees and Students were added, which are different entities in different databases.

Now I need to have 2 separate mobile applications, one for employees and one for students, both with oAuth authentication.

Is there a way to have a single instance of IDSrv4 and ASP.Identity that could handle authentication for these 3 user types but without having to merge them all into a single database table? They have totally different requirements and the login details may overlap thus need to remain in separate databases/tables with different login forms.

Those users eventually will share scopes (require access to shared apis).

The subject would be different for each type, ie: `user-1` vs `employee-1` vs `student-1`.

Possible solutions I am trying to avoid:

- Have separate IDSrv4 instances that would authenticate each user type
- Merge all 3 user types into 1 single table and use a single IDSrv4 instance

Comment: You can have 1 IdSrv4 and multiple client configurations with different scope configurations, you can apply different policies to them but that requires that all users must be in the IdSrv4 DB.

Comment: I don't agree- IDS4 doesn't care how users are stored or where - as long as you're able to figure out which DB to go to based on the context you're given you can do what you like.
The pain will be making ASP.Net Identity work how you want - you may have to dump that and roll your own equivalent capabilities.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I assumed. I'll do some asp.net identity experiments and see how it goes. @Eldar: thanks, that's what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: I see there's a way to use different cookie auth schemes for each user type, and that works well by implementing different logins and authenticating against the specific scheme. The problem is that IDS4 when checking if the user is authenticated, it uses either the default cookie scheme or one set in the IDS4 configs. I couldn't find a workaround for this. Being able to set cookie scheme per client would be great.

Comment: For now, it seems as it would be hard to pull this off using IDS4 as it does not support multi-session scenarios. More and more it seems like I will have to run separate IDS4 services for each user type.

Answer (score 0):

IdentityServer does not care how you authenticate your users and you could add to your AccountController class logic to lookup the users in either database and then sign-in the user to IdentityServer.

[image]

Besides **AccountController** you also need to tweak the **IProfileService**, as it needs to be able to lookup the user after sign-in.
[image]

Comment: Hi Tore. Thx for the reply. What I observed is that only one auth scheme can be set for IDS4 (or default one is used). Having multiple user types you would probably have a separate auth scheme for each as you could be requesting access tokens for multiple user types at the same time. Hitting the authorize endpoint will always use that single scheme configured. Also IDS4 sets a single session cookie. I haven't verified but someone mentioned logging out would be a problem as IDS4 doesn't handle multiple session. Maybe I'm missing something, will do more research.

Comment: As I said in my answer, IdentityServer does not care about how you login the user or how the login/consent screen look like. So, you can let the user choose how to login and then tell IdentityServer the user to sign-in. The password check is done by you in the AccountController that you "own", not inside the IdentityServer engine.

Comment: In my idea I want to have only one scheme/cookie and one type of tokens beteween IdentityServer and your client/APIs. Inside the access/ID-token you can include a claim that explains the source of the user.

Comment: Yes, that would be optimal, but using a single scheme for both types will you be able to handle `asp.identity` login/logout for both types separately? Asp.Identity will use a single cookie for both in that case. Also hitting the IDS4 authorize and check session endpoints will not work without some rewriting, if even possible. Regarding multiple sessions Dominick Baier mentioned they are not supported. Anyway I'll do more research with the test project.

Comment: I haven't used ASP.NET Identity that much myself, but in the end you want one scheme to your tokens and  in theory you can have for example many copies of the AccountController class, each one signing in and authenticating usres against the different databases ... is one way